# Display instructions on how to display widget after install

Tags: android, widget, installation, instructions

Some users (approx 15%) that download my widgets from the android market do not know how to display them on the home screen.  I would like for a screen to pop up that gives instructions on how to do this when the user clicks the item in the android pull down window (the one that says install was successful). Is this possible?  If so how is it done?

Answer (score 0):

If the widget has an associated app, clicking that line following installation would open the app, which could provide the instruction you want to provide.